# the difference of "for myself "and "on my own behalf"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “And you are ill?” added the surgeon, compassionately, for the tone
>   was that of a person in pain. “I am,” was the reply—“very ill; not
>   bodily, but mentally. It is not **for myself, or on my own behalf**,”
>   continued the stranger, “that I come to you. If I laboured under
>   bodily disease, I should not be out, alone, at such an hour, or on
>   such a night as this; and if I were afflicted with it, twenty-four
>   hours hence, God knows how gladly I would lie down and pray to die.

What is the difference between "for myself" and "on my own behalf"?
source [THE BLACK VEIL](http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Dickens/Dickens_Veil.pdf#search=%27The+Black+Veil+by+Charles+Dickens+full%27)

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit more context to Malvolio's answer:

The passage is attempting to get across the meaning that someone else requires the surgeon's aid. By saying "not for myself, or on my own behalf", it implies that she is there "on someone else's behalf", or to represent/benefit someone else. (This becomes clear if you read on a little further in the passage.)

---

(At the risk of this turning into literary analysis)

In context, there isn't really any difference in meaning between "I'm not here for myself" and "I'm not here on my own behalf", so it's possible that both have been included to emphasise the point, by saying the same thing twice, in a slightly different way each time.

Comment: There can be a difference but here it is just an intensifier. :)

Answer (score 0):

"On my own behalf" has a very narrow meaning: you are doing something for your own direct benefit.  A lawyer acting *pro se* is pleading on his own behalf.  A doctor with a headache who prescribes himself a strong painkiller is acting on his own behalf.

"For myself" covers a range of reflexive acts.  You can be cooking for yourself, shopping for yourself, anything you plausibly do for another person you can do "for yourself".

Most things you do for yourself you are doing, in some sense, for your benefit, because you are not a crazy person, but you can "cause trouble for yourself", but "causing trouble on your behalf" is not even linguistically sensible.

Comment: If you cook for yourself, you are doing it on your own behalf. Why would  you be cooking for yourself on behalf of someone else? Possible, not probably.

Comment: @Lambie I guess an example would be a head chef at a restaurant. They cook for themself (not for another chef), but you could say they do not cook on their own behalf (they won't eat the food). Still somewhat ambiguous though, I guess...